# The answer must have a score of at least +2

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, bounty

The question title is excerpted from [META FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/266543).

The sentence is pretty confusing and I am just curious.

Is it 2 or above ?

or

Is it above 2 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"At least +2" means 2 or above.

Baseline score is 0; "At least +2" would be "At least 0+2", or "At least 2".

Answer (score 10):

It must have a score of at least *positive* 2, meaning greater than or equal to two.